# operator overloading for enum type

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```
#include<iostream>


enum week
{
    sun=1,
    mon,
    tue,
    wed,
    thr,
    fri,
    sat
};


week &operator++(week& day,int)
{
    if(day==sat)
        day=sun;
    else
        day++; // This expression
   return day;
}


int main()
{
    week day=sun;
    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++,day++)
    {
        std::cout<<day;
    }
}
```

In the expression `day++` it goes into infinite recursion.

If I cast it like `((int)day)++` the compiler gives the following  error:

```
      error: lvalue required as increment operand
```

If I change the line to `day=week(((int)day)+1)` it works. But how to fix the above code so it works with the `++` operator?

Comment: Why do you insist on `++` operator. What's wrong with `day=week(((int)day)+1);`? You can also write simply `return day = week(((int)day%7)+1);`.

Comment: I would ask for is there any option available for using ++ operator.

Comment: [Unscoped enumerations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Unscoped_enumeration) are basically glorified symbolic integer constants. You might have better luck with stronger typed [scoped enumerations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations).

Comment: I suggest not relying on self-modifying `++` as much.  `week next(week day) { if (day==sat) return sun; return week(((int)day)+1);` and in the for loop, use `day = next(day)`.

Comment: In addition to what everyone else said, your POST-increment operator is returning the wrong value anyway. POST-increment (day++) is supposed to return *a copy of the previous value* prior to incrementing. Your code is more suited for a PRE-increment (++day) operator instead, which returns a *reference to the modified value*. See [Increment/decrement operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) for more details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way round the compiler error is to cast to a reference instead

```
((int&)day)++;
```

but you should take care that the backing type of the `enum` is an `int`:

```
enum week : int
{
    // and so on
```

If that's not to your taste and would rather have the compiler decide the backing type for you then use

```
((std::underlying_type<week>::type&)day)++;
```

Answer (score 5):

The default increment operator doesn't work well with enums. You'll have to overload the increment operator (with your `week(((int)day)+1)` logic) and handle the wrap-around in that overload function instead.

Answer (score 4):

`(int)day` returns an int, which you try to increment by ++ operator. So basically you do something like `... = 5++` which is not legal.